# Enable scrolling or create new layout for landscape view

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-constraintlayout

I'm developing an android app where in I have the login button at the bottom of the layout. On rotation of the device to landscape view, the button disappears making the UI pretty much useless.

So my question is: **Should I rearrange views in the existing layout and enable scrolling or create a new layout for landscape view?**

If you agree with the first option, how can I make sure that the login button stays intact at the bottom in the portrait as well as in landscape view?

Comment: The best way is defined your own landscape layout in `layout-land`. Anyway, if the button disappears when rotating the device, something wrong you did defining your portrait layout, because in some small screens even the portrait layout could not be working.

Comment: Try  ScrollView  as parent for your layout

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a landscape layout should be your best option. With this, you can setup exactly what you want for each orientations.

Answer (score 0):

Add ScrollView as a parent to the xml file of your login page

Example

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <--your layout

</ScrollView>
```